# Installing Ruby 2.0.0 on Mac 10.7.5 "requirements_port_libs_install"

Tags: gcc, osx-lion, rvm, ruby-2.0

I originally installed ruby 1.9.3 with an installer from here: http://railsinstaller.org/
Now I want to install Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4

so I used rvm witch that installer had already installed

```
rvm install 2.0.0
```

but that failed with:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for smf, might require sudo password.
-bash: requirements_port_lib_installed: command not found
-bash: requirements_port_lib_installed: command not found
-bash: requirements_port_lib_installed: command not found
-bash: requirements_port_lib_installed: command not found
-bash: requirements_port_lib_installed: command not found
-bash: requirements_port_lib_installed: command not found
-bash: requirements_port_lib_installed: command not found
-bash: requirements_port_lib_installed: command not found
-bash: requirements_port_lib_installed: command not found
-bash: requirements_port_lib_installed: command not found
-bash: requirements_port_lib_installed: command not found
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, libyaml, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl, sqlite..
Error running 'requirements_port_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config libyaml readline libxml2 libxslt libksba openssl sqlite',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg config_libyaml_readline_libxml2_libxslt_libksba_openssl_sqlite.log
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
You can get help using IRC: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm
```

the log reported this :

```
 [2013-03-29 01:34:58] requirements_port_libs_install
```

/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/logging: line 141: requirements_port_libs_install: command not found

after I ran:

```
rvm requirements
```

but that failed with the same message and log
I read that it could be a problem with my version of the compiler form xCode so I downloaded the new one from the app store and installed the command line utilities from that, still the same message.

I know this is not really an interesting question but help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug and is fixed for `rvm get head` it will be released soon as `1.19.1` => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1736